# flashbuilder s:datagrid checkbox doesnt show up

Tags: checkbox, datagrid

flashbuilder s:datagrid checkbox doesnt show up, am I doing something wrong?

```
<s:DataGrid x="9.7" y="123.35" height="467" width="999" variableRowHeight="true">

            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="SEL" resizable="false" sortable="false" width="30">
                        <s:itemRenderer>
                                        <fx:Component>
                              <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                <s:CheckBox />
                            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                                         </fx:Component>
                                </s:itemRenderer>
                        </s:GridColumn>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="受注日" resizable="false" width="80"/>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="件名" dataField="col1" width="400"/>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="本体金額" width="100" dataField="col5" resizable="false"/>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="消費税" width="80" dataField="col6" resizable="false"/>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="見積金額" width="100" dataField="col7"  resizable="false"/>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="納品予定日" dataField="col8"/>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
```

it should be displayed on the left side of the grid, but it's empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even I have come across similar situation until i noticed I have not provided my grid with any data, so as soon as I fed it with some data, it did show the itemrenderer.